# How do you successfully read a response from php with jquery.ajax() method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to write a simple program where my script will use the `jquery.ajax()` function to send data to the server and the server will simply echo back the same data.  After the data is echoed back, my javascript simply alerts the value of the data, however, whenever my php successfully reads the data and responds accordingly, the success function in the ajax object never gets called, however when something on the php side fails the success function is getting called.  I feel like I'm doing everything right, and I can't figure out what's going on.  Here's my javscript:

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('form');
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var userInput = $('#field').val();
        var input = {'input': userInput};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mirror.php",
            data: input,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                alert(response.data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here's my php:

```
<?
    $data = $_POST['input'];
    print $data;

    $response = array("data" => $data);

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

With this code, the php always responds with the proper data, however the alert() function is never called for whatever reason.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead. What data are you sending?

Comment: I have, when I enter 'stuff' into the form the console shows the server responds with {"data":"stuff"} which should be expected, yes?

Comment: doesn't it also respond with the result of `print $data;`?

Comment: Yes, it prints the same thing but to the other console

Comment: Your response, as you have it now, should be `stuff{"data":"stuff"}` which is not valid JSON. If it isn't you're not telling us the whole story.

Comment: `print` and `echo` basically do the same thing. I don't think you're ever getting past `print $data;`

Comment: The response is `stuff{"data":"stuff"}`, sorry it wouldn't let me edit my comment

Comment: I just removed the `print $data;` and it worked, thank y'all so much I had no clue those were the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not outputting from PHP what you think you are -

```
<?
    $data = $_POST['input'];
    print $data; // echo's the input

    $response = array("data" => $data);

    echo json_encode($response); // adds JSON

?>
```

If the input is "foo" you'll get back `foo{"data":"foo"}` See the extra "foo"? That's bad.

Comment out the `print $data;` line and you'll get back nothing *but* JSON.